# When is an opinion wrong and why exactly?

Tags: truth

People say that it's not an opinion when it's verifiable, or backed with up conclusive facts. "Conclusive facts" are subjective though, and vary from testing. An example would be an argument over the statement: **"Masturbation is common among adolescent females."** The statement was claimed to be an opinion.

Is it an opinion to believe the latter or is it a fact? There's no one-off here; different studies say completely different things, but most always present that it's something that's done; and the people in question themselves can answer to the question outside of scientific studies and verify truths of questioning as well.

People will also tend to call off any statement as opinion if they disagree with it (some people), such as to make it seem invalid or to invalidate the message expressed as indifferent to one's own personal feelings.

A scientific study will say that it is provably true for commonplace when a certain number state yes, but if a portion always lies, the results are invalid from conclusive factuality. If a study asks groups of 100 teens in segments across the country this very question and an estimated 1-30 were postulated to deny doing so (despite possibly doing it), you can have roughly 1/3 of all test subjects lying, which skews evidence when presented factually. **University of Michigan claims that 1/4 of teen adolescent females masturbate to orgasm by age 15**. Is that evidence of fact to make the claim above or is it still an opinion?

Comment: When it's on the Internet and I disagree!! By the way a philosopher would point out, regarding your example, that the word "common" is the problem. It's a Sorites problem in fact. When does something rare become common? Is it at 10%, 11%, 12%, 12.5%, etc. Vague terms make for bad examples. "It's hot today." Well if it's 60 degrees Farenheit and you just came in from the South Pole, then it's hot. But if you just came from the Equator, it's not hot. That's not a problem with logic, it's a problem with assigning clear meanings to vague words. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this question comes down to defining what is an "opinion."

Comment: Re: `"Conclusive facts" are subjective though` - A properly conducted survey has known confidence levels and took steps to correct for bias. Done properly, a study will give you not just a number but an error margin as well. For most survey-type studies, if you could somehow sample absolutely everybody the actual number would fall between the low and high value 95% of the time. However, the tabloid version of "Conclusive FACTS Inside!" is (IMO) a sure sign that whatever study is being cited is either a) grotesquely misrepresented, or b) fundamentally flawed in design. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't opinions, they're either facts or falsehoods.  Opinions cannot be proven correct or incorrect.  You can, at least in theory, prove or disprove those two claims you stated (Although the baseline for what's considered "common" needs to be defined).

And there's no such thing as wrong opinions.  Only stupid opinions.

Answer (score 0):

To most people, "common" translates to some form of "normal" or "regularity"; somewhere in that range in some mash-up of those two terms. When the statement is made (masturbation is common among) it purports that masturbation is a regularity/normality. A person will easily refute this when taken into consideration the scope of their experiences. For example, a 90 year old man may think adolescent females do not masturbate because he's never heard one say they did or because no one has told him, and because he's never researched into female sexuality. Many studies confirm that plenty of women masturbate, but less focus on teenage girls in particular. "Common" presents a problem because it presents no precise meaning.

Does "common" mean "1/4 of girls by age 15 do it at regular intervals"?

Does "common" mean shorthand for "most do it in regular intervals"?

Does "common" supposed to mean an unknown assortment do it, but no specifics?

Your statement is not exactly wrong or right -- but it does have facts to support your point of view on it being "regularly done" to some degree. Specifics make this vague and hard to narrow down more though.

Answer (score 0):

**Opinions are all we have.** They never turn into a fact once you have done some research on that matter. Even if you read all books on a given subject and ask all scientists about it in the end of the day you will have an opinion - not a fact.

That's not because we are unable to know anything or because truth does not exist. This is because of what we do with a sentence when we think it's true: We believe it; we have a new opinion. Let's assume, a certain sentence or proposition is true e.g. the proposition that the sun is hot. When I believe that the sun is hot, what I'm actually doing is thinking that it is a fact that the sun is hot. But that is a thought, a belief, an opinion. "It is a fact that the sun is hot" is an opinion itself.

Even scientist are not working with something else as their opinions on how the world works. But opinions can be justified in different degrees. If you researched something pretty well you might call it "justified belief". If you are right about that topic, you have something Plato called "knowledge": [Justified, true belief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge). But even justified, true belief is in its core something that you belive, a thought, an opinion.

Wrong is an opinion, when the proposition you believe is wrong. Now how do you find out if it is wrong? That's the huge field of [epistemology](/questions/tagged/epistemology). But to cut a long story short: Knowledge is hard to come by, because for every opinion you need a reason. A reason is nothing but an opinion. So you will need a reason for your reason. And a reason for that reason. And some say, you will never be done reasoning, and [you will never know anything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skepticism). Others say that there are some things that are so basic, so evident that for those you need no reason, [like perception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism) or Descartes [Cogito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditations_on_First_Philosophy). And others again say that knowledge is possible if all the different beliefs you have are [well interconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherentism). But all of this is a huge field!